# Persistent data for winform c#

Tags: winforms

I have a web poster application and I want to create a "Definition" file for it. Basically just a bunch of strings I import into the program at startup. I want them in an external source so I can update it without changing the executable.

I was thinking of creating a new static class, say "PosterDefinition", and on the startup of the application import the definition file, and set the PosterDefintion values from there.

As for how I will save it, maybe serialize the data from the program itself (a one time process).

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you save it in an XML file.  This would allow you to get the data quickly using LINQ-XML.  What you could do is make properties that look at the file for making changes.  You could cache values in the Application object.  After a few requests, or after each one, check on the file.  Because LINQ, or better yet PLINQ, excecutes quickly, the requests would not take long.

Here is an example XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Definition>
    <Item>
        <Title>t</Title>
        <Something>Pie</Something>
    </Item>
</Definition>
```

And here is how to access the Something of an item with Title t

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

XElement element = XElement.Load("definitions.xml");
XElement item = (from item in element.Elements()
                where item.Elements().Where(i => (string)i.Element("Title") == "t")
                select item.Element("Something")).First();
```

I havn't tested this and I am bad at LINQ so check this.

Comment: XML can be read easily by the user, I don't want this to happen. I will try to use binary formatter.